# Changing color of specific ChartJS - AngularChartJS point

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

I have a line chart made with AngularJS - http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/#getting_started - Chart.js.

```
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" data="data"
  labels="labels" legend="true" series="series"
  click="onClick" options="options">
</canvas> 

$scope.labels = labels_filtered;
$scope.series = [word];
$scope.data = [_.values(response.graph_values)];
```

Is it possible to set a different color for some point in the graph depending on some conditions? (for example: for points with value > 10 set color red, else set color green)

[Edit] Link to small demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/S0W5wPznMu4bCxRjOppl?p=preview . What I would like is to set the colors of the dots with 80,81 values with red and the other points with another color.

Thanks.

Comment: could you attached fiddle or plunkr..

Comment: [link to plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/S0W5wPznMu4bCxRjOppl?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to manually set point color of your chart:

`myLineChart.datasets[0].points[4].fillColor =   "rgba(000,111,111,55)" ;`

Example:

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("Line_Chart", ["chart.js"]);
  app.controller('LineChartController', function($scope) {
    $scope.labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
    $scope.series = ['Series B'];
   
    $scope.data = [
      [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]  
    ];
    
    $scope.onClick = function(points, evt) {
      console.log(points, evt);
    };
    
    $scope.$on("create", function(evt, chart) {
      chart.datasets[0].points[4].fillColor = "red";
      chart.update();
    });
  });  
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/02639948a90edf92f018804ec25baea9fef71a84/angular-chart.js"></script>

    <body ng-app="Line_Chart">
      <div ng-controller="LineChartController">
        <canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" data="data" labels="labels" legend="true" series="series" click="onClick" options="options" colours="colours" chart="mychart">
        </canvas>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: can you show me a demo? because I tried it here http://plnkr.co/edit/S0W5wPznMu4bCxRjOppl?p=preview and it doesn't seem that it is working

Comment: See the example I provide

Comment: this is a better option than onAnimationComplete

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the angular version exposes the chart points directly.

But you could use the animation complete handler to update the point colors once the rendering is done. You can set the animation complete handler using the ChartJsProvider that the angular-chart.js provides

```
  var app = angular.module("Line_Chart", ["chart.js"]).config(function(ChartJsProvider) { 
    ChartJsProvider.setOptions({ onAnimationComplete: function(){
      this.datasets[0].points[2].fillColor = "red";
      this.update()
    } }); 
  })
```

Plunkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/ggqcmpkhFXsinnm9aDbM?p=preview

Comment: That said, this isn't a good solution designwise. The better solution would be enable binding to the points (on the directive) and use that - but you are basically modifying angular-chart.js then.

Comment: +1, because i though of this but forgot .update() so it was partialy working :) See my answer for an example using the `create` event.

Comment: you'll probably have to do it in the update event as well.

Comment: Not needed, the update does not change colors so it remember what we have changed. You can see it [here](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/blob/ba0cb801cf605710bd3df7c4cda0f6ff6cf6e08f/angular-chart.js#L278)

Comment: OP is planning on changing the graph depending on some conditions (as per the question)

Answer (score 1):

Solutions that utilize `chart.datasets[0].points[4].fillColor = "red";` type code no longer work in chart.js v2+.

However, dataset properties such as pointBorderColor accept arrays, which can be really useful. This lets you create an array of colors (or other properties) and you can set different properties for specific data points. You can also access the property in the array later and change it.

Example:

```
data: {
      labels: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ],
      datasets: [
        {
          fill: false,
          lineTension: 0.4,
          backgroundColor: [ "rgba(117, 201, 196,0.4)", "rgba(117, 201, 196,0.4)", "rgba(117, 201, 196,0.4)", "rgba(117, 201, 196,0.4)", "rgba(117, 201, 196,0.4)", "rgba(117, 201, 196,0.4)", "rgba(117, 201, 196,0.4)", "rgba(117, 201, 196,0.4)", "rgba(117, 201, 196,0.4)", "rgba(117, 201, 196,0.4)" ],
          borderColor: "rgba(117, 201, 196, 0.8)",
          borderCapStyle: 'butt',
          borderDash: [],
          borderDashOffset: 0.0,
          borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
          pointBorderColor: [ "rgb(117, 201, 196)", "rgb(117, 201, 196)", "rgb(117, 201, 196)", "rgb(117, 201, 196)", "rgb(117, 201, 196)", "rgb(117, 201, 196)", "rgb(117, 201, 196)", "rgb(117, 201, 196)", "rgb(117, 201, 196)", "rgb(117, 201, 196)" ],
          pointBackgroundColor: [ "#fff", "#fff", "#fff", "#fff", "#fff", "#fff", "#fff", "#fff", "#fff", "#fff" ],
          pointBorderWidth: 1,
          pointHoverRadius: 5,
          pointHoverBackgroundColor: [ "rgb(117, 201, 196)", "rgb(117, 201, 196)", "rgb(117, 201, 196)", "rgb(117, 201, 196)", "rgb(117, 201, 196)", "rgb(117, 201, 196)", "rgb(117, 201, 196)", "rgb(117, 201, 196)", "rgb(117, 201, 196)", "rgb(117, 201, 196)" ],
          pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
          pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
          pointRadius: [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
          pointHitRadius: 10,
          data: [ 1, 3, 6, 12, 18, 28, 17, 10, 3, 2 ],
          spanGaps: false
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another approach, but it is not the best solution.

In the file Chart.js I have changed this section of code by putting [index] to the pointColor object:

```
helpers.each(dataset.data,function(dataPoint,index){   
   datasetObject.points.push(new this.PointClass({
      value : dataPoint,
      label : data.labels[index],
      datasetLabel: dataset.label,
      strokeColor : dataset.pointStrokeColor,
      fillColor : dataset.pointColor[index],
```

and in the Angular Controller I put this line:

```
$scope.colours = [{pointColor:colours, fillColor: "#E7EDF0", strokeColor: "#A9C4D2"}];
```

where colours is an array of colors for each point in the graph.

*To make sure that is also accepts single values, one solution would be to check the type of object dataset.pointColor is and use it as single value or array.